# Подключение плагина jQuery

Tags: jquery, плагин

Как подключить плагин jQuery nestedSortable? 
В инструкции указана команда "meteor add ilikenwf:nested-sortable". Метеор установлен, но такой командой подключить плагин не получается. Я новичок, может что-то не так делаю.

---

В итоге этот meteor вообще не нужен. Запустила без него.

Comment: А какая ошибка выдается?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov 

Я скачала пример с git, его структура: 
meteor, 
.eslintrc, 
.jscsrc, 
README.md, 
bower.json, 
example.html, 
jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js, 
package.js, 
package.json.
Если запускать из папки всего проекта, то:
To create a new Meteor project:
meteor create <project name>
For example:
meteor create myapp
Создаю каталог myapp командой "meteor create myapp" из нее в командной строке ввожу "meteor add ilikenwf:nested-sortable", и выводится: => Errors while parsing arguments: 

While adding package ilikenwf:nested-sortable:
error: no such package

Comment: Значит, пакета нету в репозитории meteor'а. Вам придётся ставить его вручную. Я, к сожалению, вообще не программировал в node.js и не могу ничего посоветовать.